# How to show that $f_n(x)=n \cdot \sin(n^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot x)$ does not converge pointwisely for x other than $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

As n the title, I know that it's true but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: What kind of convergence do you need to disprove? Pointwise?

Comment: Yeah, pointwise.

Comment: Is this homework? Why include the minus sign?

Comment: The minus sign doesn't matter. It's just the last part of a bigger proof that I've already done. Everything works fine if that part doesn't converge pointwisely. It seems intuitive but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: It was needlessly harsh to have closed this. The question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x > 0$.
If $n \sin (n^{3/2} x)$ is bounded for large $n$ then $a(n) = n^{3/2} x / \pi$ must become close to an integer (in the sense that the distance to the nearest integer tends to zero).
If so, the same holds for the consecutive differences $b(n) = a(n) - a(n-1)$.
Since $a(n)$ is comparable to $n^{3/2}$, $b(n)$ is comparable to $n^{1/2}$, and $b(n) - b(n-1)$ is comparable to $n^{-1/2}$ so tends to zero.
Hence $b(n)$ must tend to a constant $z \in \mathbf{Z}$ and be comparable to $n^{1/2}$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n(x)$ is pointwise convergent, $\forall x\in\Omega, \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$.

In other words, given any $\epsilon >0, \forall x\in\Omega$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall i,j>N$, $|f_i(x) - f_j(x)|<\epsilon$.

But clearly $|f_i(x) - f_j(x)| = |i \cdot \sin(i^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot x)-j \cdot \sin(j^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot x)|$ is not bounded above by arbitrary $\epsilon$ $\forall i,j>N$, except when $x=0$. Thus it is not pointwise convergent except when $x=0$.